# App related to recipes, shopping list, menu, and diary

Tags: android, database, images, productivity, cooking

I am looking for an app which can import recipes from Google Keep (for instance, recipes may be defined in Google Keep using the Cooking label).

The app, lists the recipes, on the left, and they may be searched.

The right part of the app is split into two. Here we find the shopping list, at the top. Here the user plans what they need to buy prior to leaving the house. For this, they select the recipe, from the searchable recipe list (on the left), or from the planned menu (a scrollable list below).

When planning what to buy, the user clicks on the recipe, and a popup shows up where the user, for each ingredient, figures out if it is already in stock (fridge, cupboards, drawers, under the table, etc.), in which case they click on the stock button and the item is not added to the list, or, the user can select list, and the item is added to the shopping list, or, skip, in which case the recipe will be prepared without the given ingredient (or they may even click substitute in which case the ingredient substituted will be added to the list, and to the recipe in the notes for the recipe).

The menu below lists what meals the user, in their spare time, using their phone, has planned for the days ahead.

There is also a diary, where the user, decides, what to eat, on a specific day (the menu may be bypassed).

The menu can be a rotary menu.

Each recipe may have more than one image taken with the camera or from storage, a recipe description, and a scalable list of recipe items for number of people (which may include children).

Thanks.